# Can't create mkmapview in the main thread

Tags: objective-c, ios8, mkmapview, viewcontroller

I have a main VC that has a button. This button creates a new VC which contains a MKMapView IBOutlet.

When I click the button, the title message is returned in the console.

I tried to instantiate the mapview in the initwithcoder method and also tried using (the selector just alloc/inits the map):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initMap) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    } 

    return self;
}
```

If I set the map VC to be the initial VC, all goes fine.

Any enlightenment?